# Copy an existing Excel recordset to Access table

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for an elegant method to dump an existing Excel recordset (created from another database, not copied to an Excel sheet) into another Access database.

I know I can loop through all rows in the recordset, but I am looking for a more straightforward way.

Comment: What database are you creating it from? You could do with providing some example code in order to get an answer. Why are you using excel as a middle man?

Comment: Basically I have to use Excel as the middle man.

Comment: With regards to the sample code, which portion would you like to see? As for the source database, it is a recordset that comes from a stored procedure on a server side database. I dont have any rights on this one.

Comment: And the Access database is a local database that I will use as a "buffer".

Comment: would be nice to see what object you are using to read the data, what type of server database it is, and why can't you use access?

Comment: Access can connect to any database that excel can, and usually you will be able to `select into` a table rather than populating a recordset in memory with the data then writing it to the database.

Comment: So you suggest a direct connection from Access to the server database. But the final users will not have Access on their computers. They only have Excel. I will post code samples

Comment: Ok, but access can create excel files easily, excel is your endgame, access is your middle man. You can write vba in access, just as in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I think your best solution is going to be a [linked table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-link-to-data-in-another-Access-database-095ab408-89c7-45b3-aac2-58036e45fcf6) in ms-access.

Once you have linked your table, you can run a macro in access to export what you want to excel quite easily using [`DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793.aspx)

The code for that looks like this:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
       "Select * from TableName where criteria1='True'","C:\Temp\MyFileName.xls"
```

Comment: Hi Nick, and thanks for your help. But I have to keep things running from Excel.

Comment: For now, I copied the initial recordset into an excel worksheet, and I am pushing it to Access table using an INSERT INTO sql query.